transformers No module named 'keras.engine'
I have transformers 4.25.1 and Keras 3.4.1 with Python 3.9 under Windows.
permutation_importance uses transformers\utils\import_utils.py
which produces:
line 1095, in _get_module
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.modeling_tf_utils 
because of the following error 
No module named 'keras.engine'


Update Python 3.12.6
